# Excel formulas to Javascript Math

Tags: javascript, math, excel-formula

I have a number of formulas which are in Excel form and I know I have asked for help on these kind of things before but I have three more formulas that I cannot work out how to express in javascript.

the variables are

```
var J17 = 6.50;
var C19 = 5;
var C20 = 6;
var C22 = 0.5;
var E26 = 0.5; 
var F26 = 0.5;
```

Formula 1:

> =1/(1+J$17*C$22*0.01)^((E26/C$22)) - Should return 0.968523002

Formula 2:

> =IF(F26=C$19,100,0) - Should return 0.00

Formula 3:

> =IF(E26>C$19,0,C$20*C$22) - Should return 3.00

Thats is my main problem is with Formula 1, I know that the `^` is expressed using `Math.pow` but I cannot work out where it should go in the javascript expression. I have had a try at this:

```
var calcValue = (1 /  Math.pow(1 + J17 * C22 * 0.01), (E26/C22) );
```

But it returns `infinity`

Comment: Should that be `* 0.01`?

Comment: Your right apologies will update

Comment: Your `IF` statements can be replaced with the format `someCondition? valueiftrue : valueiffalse`. So for the first one: `F26 === C19? 100 : 0`

Comment: @MattBurland what would be the statement for this ```=IF(E26>C$19,0,E26)```

Comment: Well, `E26>C19` would be your condition, `0` would be your `valueiftrue` and `E26` would be your value if false. So just plug them in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a paren out of place:

```
var calcValue = (1 /  Math.pow(1 + J17 * C22 * 0.01), (E26/C22)
                ^
```

Try:

```
var calcValue = 1 /  Math.pow((1 + J17 * C22 * 0.01), (E26/C22))
                             ^
```

For what it's worth, your original formula has a useless extra set of parens too: `((E26/C$22))`

**EDIT** Updated `+ 0.01` to `* 0.01`, as your original post had that same error.  ;)

Comment: Thanks that is producing a result (http://jsfiddle.net/9pgrw20f/) but not the expected

Comment: Doesn't give the right answer unless you replace the `+0.01` with `*0.01`

Comment: Also, you only actually need `1 /  Math.pow(1 + J17 * C22 * 0.01, E26/C22 );` Those inner brackets aren't doing anything.